# Sum of two textfields - javascript

Tags: javascript, sum

I found [this][1], rather difficult, javascript example online and I've implemented it with success in my website.

However, I would like to get the result of, in this case, the two subtotals in one new text-field.

The traditional `getElementbyId` and `total.value=total` didn't work out.

**EDIT**

```
 function doMath()
{
    // Capture the entered values of two input boxes
    var twogiga = document.getElementById('twogig').value;
    var fourgiga = document.getElementById('fourgig').value;

    // Add them together and display
    var sum = parseInt(twogiga) + parseInt(fourgiga);
    document.getElementById('total').value = parseInt(sum);
}
```

This is the javascript I use. But for some reason, when I have just one value (`twogig`), the `total` is set as NaN.  What is wrong with my script?

Comment: try to build some html first so you and us get a better idea

Comment: ok, no problem. I can give the HTML to you in a sec

Comment: Not clear with the questions, some more details required to answer ur query

Comment: you have a lost link on `this` in your first line.

Comment: Ok. I've got four textfield (T1, T2, T3 and T4). Two of them (T1, T3) are accessible for the user. They can enter a number. This number is multiplied and the subtotal displayed in the corresponding others fields (T2, T4). Now I want to add a fifth field (T5) with the sum of the two subtotals. All of this should happen `onChange()`

Comment: Please post the JavaScript functions you already have to do the subtotals (if I read your question right you already have this working?), because the extra totalling that you want is probably just another line or two. (Don't make us reinvent the wheel.)

Comment: @nnnnnn, I added the javascript I used.

Comment: Not the problem with your script, but if you've already used `parseInt` on all of the numbers you're going to be adding together you don't need to use it again on the sum.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, if you have assigned ID's to text inputs, for example: <input type="text" id="my_input" />, then you can call it with document.getElementById('my_input').value.

So:

```
<input type="text" id="my_input1" />
<input type="text" id="my_input2" />
<input type="button" value="Add Them Together" onclick="doMath();" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    function doMath()
    {
        // Capture the entered values of two input boxes
        var my_input1 = document.getElementById('my_input1').value;
        var my_input2 = document.getElementById('my_input2').value;

        // Add them together and display
        var sum = parseInt(my_input1) + parseInt(my_input2);
        document.write(sum);
    }
</script>
```

Naturally, that is a very basic script, it doesn't check to make sure the entered values are numbers. We have to convert the fields into integers, otherwise they'll be strings (so 2+2 would equal 22). When the button is clicked, the function is called, which makes a variable for each input box, converts them to ints, adds them, and outputs our sum.

Comment: You should be defining a radix for the `parseInt` function, otherwise your results will be messed up.

Comment: Well, that's completely optional, and unless you want to use a hex or octa, it will default to decimal. Of course, if you do want to use a radex, use: parseInt(my_input1, 10); (10 means decimal). Personally, I don't really use them at all, and it would only mess up if the user tries to enter a number that starts with a 0 or an "x".

Comment: Ok, that's helpful! How do I get the value `sum` in a defined textfield? `myText.value = sum`?

Comment: Make an input field, give it an id, for example `my_sum`, and then use: `document.getElementById('my_sum').value = sum`;

Comment: Ok, seems like a good solution. But whenever I enter just 1 textfield, I get an `NaN` error. So both fields are required to make the sum?

Comment: NaN means Not a Number. I forgot, you have to use `parseInt(my_input1)` in place, like in the example above. Otherwise, it thinks it's a string.

Comment: So right now, there is `var sum = parseInt(twogiga) + parseInt(fourgiga);
        document.getElementById('total').value = parseInt(sum);` correct? Still an NaN-error though...

Comment: by the way, it's not possible to place a value like this in a database with a $_POST?

Comment: @Mike If the number is zero prefixed, you will end up getting Octals -- something you will need to avoid. So it's always better to provide a radix.

Comment: Ok, what do I need to do to provide a radix?

Comment: Just use my example way above (second post): `parseInt(my_input1, 10);` The ten means that it is a decimal number. Oh, and yes, you could put it in a database, provided you pass it into a post or get form and have PHP capture that, or some other method of putting communicating with a database (PHP is my personal recommendation).

Comment: @Mike - "it would only mess up if the user tries to enter a number that starts with a 0" - because we all know that users *never* enter anything we don't want them to...

Answer (score 3):

Replace:

```
document.getElementById('total').value = parseInt(sum);
```

With:

```
document.getElementById('total').value = sum;
```

You have already done all the int-parsing you need to do.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("#value1, #value2").on('focusout', function() {
  var value2 = parseInt($("#value2").val()) > 0 ? parseInt($("#value2").val()) : 0;
  var value1 = parseInt($("#value1").val()) > 0 ? parseInt($("#value1").val()) : 0
  var sumOfValues = value1 + value2;
  console.log('Your sum is ' + sumOfValues);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="input" id="value1">
<input type="text" class="input" id="value2">
```